# How to clear history in Safari (cookies, website data, etc.)?

Tags: safari

How to clear history in Safari: visited sites, cookies, recent searches, website data, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Safari 16

In Safari 16 'Clear History' menu item was moved to 'Safari' menu tab:

[image: Safari 16 menu]

#### Safari 15

In Safari 15 and earlier 'Clear History' menu item was in 'History' menu tab:

[image: Safari 15 menu]

Answer (score 0):

To clear history and cookies, go to Settings > Safari and click Clear history and site data. Clearing Safari's history, cookies, and browsing data will not change AutoFill data.